# Reduce image size

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, file-size, file-format, posters

Hi I made a poster in photoshop but the image size is really big 15mb, as I live in a small town and have to email this to printers it is a bit of a problem. I was asked to get it down to around 4mb but I don't want it to lose its quality.  How do I reduce the size but keep quality for printing?

Comment: What size will it print? What is the current resolution?

Comment: What file formats does your printer accept? Is it necessary for your to supply a PSD or can it be in other, lossy, formats?

Comment: Keep in mind that 4mb is likely what they're asking for in order for it to email properly. 15mb really isn't that big - if you can for sure get it to 4mb without losing quality, great. There are guaranteed lossless methods of reducing the size of certain files (one of which is NOT saving as JPG by the way), but it's usually just safer and easier to find a different method of file exchange.

Answer (score 2):

`File > Save As...` choose JPG.

Set the **Quality** to **12** and save.

**DO NOT** use `Save for Web`, use `Save As..`

The difference is Save for Web will save an RGB image at low resolution. By Choosing `Save As..` you can save a CMYK JPG at high resolution.

The quality setting of 12 will retain most of the quality of the file. In fact, you probably won't be able to tell the difference between the jpg and your original file. And the resulting jpg will be much smaller in terms of file size.

Answer (score 1):

You can still email it using Google Drive, dropbox like services.

1. upload it on your google drive
2. share your link to your printer.

You will really lose quality if you reduce its size.

Comment: I'd also recommend a dropbox-type service. WeTransfer would also work just fine. Don't save down for the sake of file size. 15MB is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

you can reduce filesize by

1. flattening all layers to one.
2. reducing excessive resolution amount. 300 dpi is enough to print a3, a4 size.
3. you can try app like 7zip for compressing if they use compressed format like .7z or .zip .tar .rar.